# Pointer one linked list to another linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, structure

I'm trying to point a pointer in one structure to a node of another structure. I've been stuck on this 10 hours now. Can someone help me fix my code? I'm getting Segmentation fault at `curr_users -> playlist = p_playlists;`. Am I pointing it wrong?

```
struct playlist_ {
  int album;
  int track_num;
  struct playlist_ *next;
};
typedef struct playlist_  playlists;

struct users_ {
  int user_ID;
  struct playlist_ *playlist;
  struct users_ *next;
};
typedef struct users_ users;

int transaction(FILE *transaction_file,album *all_album){
  int transaction_id,i;
  int album_ID,
      account_number,
      add_playlist_user,
      add_playlist_album,
      add_playlist_track;

  users *head_users,*curr_users,*p_users,*users_pointer;
  playlists *head_playlists,*curr_playlists,*p_playlists,*playlist_pointer;

  head_users = NULL;

  fscanf(transaction_file,"%d\n",&account_number);

  /*Checks for empty list, if true creates the first user*/
  if( !(head_users)){
    p_users = malloc(sizeof(users ));
    p_users -> user_ID = account_number;
    head_users = p_users;
    head_users -> next = NULL;
    users_pointer = head_users;

  /*If list is not empty create new user and puts it in front of list*/
  }else{
    p_users = malloc(sizeof(users));
    p_users -> user_ID = account_number;
    curr_users = p_users;
    curr_users -> next = head_users;
    head_users = curr_users;
    users_pointer = head_users;
    }
  /*Create an empty playlist for user and set everything to null*/

  p_playlists = malloc(sizeof(playlists *));
  curr_playlists = p_playlists;
  curr_playlists -> album = 5;
  curr_playlists -> track_num = 5;
  curr_playlists -> next = NULL;
  curr_users -> playlist = p_playlists;
```

The error message received when I run this code:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00011050 in transaction (transaction_file=0xff3675cc, all_album=0x226b0)
    at functions.c:94
94            curr_users -> playlist = p_playlists;
```

Comment: Side note: you can define structures like this: `typedef struct users_ { /* whatever */ } users;` doing both definition and typedef in one statement. Furthermore, since `struct users` and `users` are two different things, you can even drop the underscore: `typedef struct users { /* */ } users;`. Even further more, you can even drop the struct name: `typedef struct { /* */ } users;` although I don't recommend this last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be in this line:

```
p_playlists = malloc(sizeof(playlists *));
```

You are allocating enough memory for a pointer to a `playlist_` structure, not enough memory for an entire `playlist_` structure. Change the line to:

```
p_playlists = malloc(sizeof(playlists));
```

to allocate enough memory for the `playlist_` struct.

**EDIT**
As indicated in the comments below, you also need to assign something to `curr_users` in the `else` block. Then, barring any other errors in your program, it should work :)

Comment: I had `p_playlists = malloc(sizeof(playlists));` but i changes it to experiment before I posted this question. I changed it back but it is still gives me the same error.

Comment: You have another error in the program. If the program enters the `if(!(head_users))` condition, then you never set the `curr_users` variable. By calling `curr_users->playlist = p_playlists;` you are dereferencing a bad variable (`curr_users`). This will cause a seg fault.

Comment: Should I change that to `if( head_users == NULL){}`?

Comment: Also, as [Shahbaz](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10002770/1304626) pointed out, you are not initializing your pointer variables. You should **always** initialize variables to some "safe" default; in the case of pointers, use `NULL` (i.e. `users* head_users = NULL`)

Comment: I did initialized it to NULL, just forgot to copy it over to the question.

Comment: No, sorry, I wasn't clear. In the `if(!(head_users))` condition, you need to assign `curr_users` to something. I don't know what your program is ultimately supposed to do, but it looks like doing `curr_users = head_users;` is the right thing (similar to how you're doing `curr_users = p_users;` in the `else` condition).

Comment: @LearningC I guess you wanted to create playlist if 'user' list is already there. So just add the condition which I edited in my post.

Answer (score 2):

People already gave the answer, but I thought I would make it more complete with a suggestion:

To minimize the confusion, to make sure you get it right, and to minimize maintenance effort in case of certain changes, always use `malloc` like this:

```
type *pointer = malloc(count * sizeof(*pointer));
```

Note that in this case, the `type` of `pointer` is only mentioned once. If it changes, you don't need to touch the rest of the code. Also, `sizeof(*pointer)` always correctly shows the size of elements that can exist in `pointer`.

---

Now to get back to your code, have you noticed that you have the following local variables:

```
users *head_users, *curr_users, *p_users, *users_pointer;
```

that are not initialized, and you are checking

```
if( !(head_users))
```

? Since your comment says `if list is empty, create the first user`, I am guessing what you need is to make `head_users` global, or pass it to `transaction` and initialize it to `NULL` at program start.

Comment: I did initialized but forgot to copy it over on the question.

Comment: Then if there is anything else in the code that is missing, put them here because the error could be there.